# How can I make this exception handling code adhere to the DRY principle?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, exception

I have a particular situation where I need to trap exceptions and return an object to the client in place of the exception. I **cannot** put the exception handling logic at a higher level i.e. wrap Foo within a try clause.

It's best to demonstrate with some sample code. The exception handling logic is clouding the intention of the method and if I have, many methods of similar intent, in the Foo class, I find myself repeating most of the catch logic.

What would be the best technique to wrap the common exception functionality in the code below?

```
public class Foo
{
     public Bar SomeMethodThatCanThrowExcepetion()
     {
          try
          {
              return new Bar().Execute();
          }
          catch(BazException ex)
          {
              WriteLogMessage(ex, Bar.ErrorCode);
              return new Bar() { ErrorMessage = ex.Message, ErrorCode = Bar.ErrorCode;}                  
          }
     }

     public Baz SomeMethodThatCanThrowExcepetion(SomeObject stuff)
     {
          try
          {
              return new Baz(stuff).Execute();
          }
          catch(BazException ex)
          {
              WriteLogMessage(ex, Baz.ErrorCode);
              return new Baz() { ErrorMessage = ex.Message, ErrorCode = Baz.ErrorCode;}                  
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Couldn't you just put your exception handling another level higher and throw an exception up the chain?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot. I am restricted here.

Comment: Is there a common base class between `Bar` and `Baz`?

Comment: Unfortunately not and this is another restriction due to the fact that Foo is a public interface.

Comment: If you can't move your exception handling to another layer, you're stuck with your implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Updated per Lee's comment*

---

One possibility is to use a generic helper method.  Something like this:

```
T TryExecute<T>(Func<T> action, int ErrorCode)
{
    try
    {
        return action();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        typeof(T).GetProperty("ErrorMessage").SetValue(result, ex.Message, null);
        typeof(T).GetProperty("ErrorCode").SetValue(result, ErrorCode, null);
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you can modify *Bar* and *Baz*, then you could improve this by placing a requirement on *T*:

```
public interface IError
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
}

T TryExecute<T>(Func<T> action, int ErrorCode) where T : IError
{
    try
    {
        return action();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        result.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        result.ErrorCode = ErrorCode;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you'd use:

```
return TryExecute<Bar>(new Bar().Execute, Bar.ErrorCode);
```

And:

```
return TryExecute<Baz>(new Baz(stuff).Execute, Baz.ErrorCode);
```

That may or may not be an over-abstraction for your particular design; the devil is in the details.

Comment: This returns null if an exception is thrown

Comment: @Lee the idea was to set *result* to the error object as needed, within the *catch* block.

Comment: Well you can't do that without any restriction on `T` or any way of creating one.

Comment: @Lee thanks, great point.  I updated my answer, which unfortunately uses reflection and magic strings now, but at least it works.

Answer (score 5):

How about a base class:

```
public class ErrorCapable {
  public string ErrorMessage { set; get; }
  public int ErrorCode { set; get; }

  public static ErrorCapable<T> Oops(Exception exc) where T : ErrorCapable, new() {
    // Code for logging error here
    return new T() { ErrorMessage = exc.Message, ErrorCode = exc.ErrorCode };
  }
}

public class Bar : ErrorCapable {
  //...
}
public class Baz : ErrorCapable {
  //...
}
```

Then in the catch, just use, for example:

```
return ErrorCapable.Oops<Bar>(ex);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need the explicit logging in every method? Instead of having the exception logic in every method, have one handler in your `Main` method of the program and handle the exceptions generically.

Also, you don't need to return an arbitrary object from a catch block should you really need the logging there, simply use `throw;` to let it wander up the stack.

Comment: Seems like the right answer to me, but in the question comments the asker says he is restricted from doing that for some reason.

Comment: See comment  in question. I am restricted from doing this. Cosider Foo  as public interface and I have no control to handle the exception at that level.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can do is something like:

```
public T TryOrDefault<T>(Func<T> act, int errorCode, Func<BazException, T> onError)
{
    try
    {
        return act;
    }
    catch(BazException ex)
    {
        WriteLogMessage(ex, errorCode);
        return onError(ex);
    }
}
```

then you can write your other methods in terms of it:

```
public Bar SomeMethodThatCanThrowException()
{
    Bar b = new Bar();
    return ExecOrDefault(() => b.Execute(), Bar.ErrorCode, ex => new Bar { ErrorMessage = ex.Message, ErrorCode = Bar.ErrorCode });
}
```